# Keyword analyzer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

is it possible to use the keyword analyzer from
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html
in searchkick?

I want a specific string analyzed in a text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can provide an ["advanced mapping"](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#advanced-mapping):

```
searchkick mappings: {
  properties: {
    name: {type: "keyword"}
  }
}
```

If you need to create a custom analyzer you can use advanced settings as well:

```
searchkick settings: {analyzers: {...}}
```